# Cannot seem to find a statistical difference despite a clear difference in the dataset

Tags: regression, stata, medicine

I've got a dataset of patients with AVM (neurosurgical disease) where you can receive endovascular treatment, surgical treatment or both (usually because endovascular treatment failed).

My outcome is post-operative modified rankings scale (MRS). I've dichotomized it by allocating 0-1 to 0 and 2-6 to 1.

I've shown that perioperative stroke is significantly associated with lower post-operative MRS. It turns out that the risk of perioperative stroke is 20% in the endovascular group, 5% in the surgical group and 38% in the "both" group.

A logistic regression using the dichotomized MRS as the dependant variable, however, cannot show this difference in MRS between groups.

A confounder I thought of, is the presentation type, where presenting with a hemorrhage is likely to be assigned surgical treatment, and this is also associated with a lower post-operative MRS.

However if I adjust for this, I still cannot seem to show a difference.

I'm using stata and my logistic regression is:

```
logistic mrsbinary i.groups AGEatpresentation SEX presentHemorrhage
```

This runs a logistic regression with the binary variable, MRS 0-1 as 0 and 2-6 as 1, as the dependant variable and the groups as a categorical variable (0 = endovascular, 1 = surgical, 2= both), the age, sex and whether the patient presented with hemorrhage.

I would suspect a statistical difference in post-operative MRS between treatments, due to the aforementioned, but I do not.

Can anyone see something I do not?

Here's my data from stataex:

```
[CODE]
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float(mrsbinary groups) byte(AGEatpresentation SEX) float(presentHemorrhage stroke)
1 0 48 1 0 0
1 0 66 2 1 1
. 0 59 1 1 0
. 0 23 2 0 0
. 1 49 2 1 0
0 0 65 2 0 0
. 0 59 2 0 1
. 2 43 1 1 0
. 0 34 2 1 0
1 2 22 2 0 0
0 0 27 1 0 0
1 1 51 1 1 0
1 0 38 2 0 0
0 0 44 1 0 1
1 1 46 2 1 0
1 0 24 2 0 0
. 0 56 1 1 1
1 2 10 2 1 0
1 0 36 1 0 0
0 0 45 2 0 0
. 0 66 2 1 0
0 0 37 2 1 0
0 0 63 2 0 0
0 0 58 2 0 0
1 2 29 2 0 1
1 2 21 2 0 0
0 1 44 1 1 0
1 0 38 2 1 0
1 0 38 2 0 0
1 0 65 1 1 1
1 0  5 2 1 0
1 0 28 2 1 0
0 0 55 1 1 0
0 0 39 2 1 0
0 1 46 2 1 0
1 0 61 1 1 1
. 2 50 1 0 0
1 2 56 1 1 0
1 0 50 2 1 1
1 0 31 1 1 0
. 0 53 1 0 0
. 2 25 1 1 0
0 0 18 2 1 0
. 2 70 1 1 0
. 0 10 2 1 0
1 0 57 1 0 1
1 0 67 1 1 0
. 0 41 2 1 0
1 0 26 2 1 0
1 1 68 2 1 0
0 0 59 2 1 0
1 0 43 1 0 1
1 0  . 1 0 1
0 0 33 2 1 0
. 0 53 2 0 1
0 0 24 2 1 0
0 0 53 2 1 0
0 0 16 2 0 0
1 0 61 2 0 0
1 2 46 2 1 1
1 0 67 1 1 1
. 2 31 2 0 0
0 0 45 1 0 0
1 1 26 1 1 0
0 0  8 2 1 0
0 0 59 2 1 0
0 0 57 1 0 1
0 0 36 1 0 0
. 0 57 2 0 0
. 0 40 1 0 0
1 0 66 1 1 0
1 1 15 2 1 0
1 1 46 2 1 0
. 0 65 1 1 1
0 0  9 1 1 0
. 0 28 1 1 0
0 0 18 1 0 0
. 2 55 2 0 1
1 0 37 1 1 1
0 0 50 1 0 0
0 1 31 2 0 1
. 0 41 1 1 0
1 2 43 1 0 1
. 0 75 2 1 0
1 2 40 1 0 1
. 0 39 1 0 0
. 0 71 1 1 0
0 0 49 2 0 0
1 2 17 2 1 0
. 0 41 1 1 1
1 0 32 2 0 0
0 0 47 1 0 0
. 0 26 2 0 1
0 2 22 1 1 0
. 0 20 1 1 0
0 0 11 2 1 0
1 2 42 2 0 1
. 1 53 2 1 0
1 0 35 2 0 0
0 0 54 2 1 1
. 0 57 2 0 0
0 0 10 1 1 0
0 0 52 2 0 0
0 0 68 1 0 0
0 1 31 1 1 0
1 0 52 1 1 0
1 0 52 1 1 0
0 0 34 1 1 0
0 0 28 2 0 0
0 0 63 1 1 0
0 1 40 2 1 0
1 0 56 1 0 0
0 0 23 2 0 0
1 2 73 2 0 1
0 2 73 1 0 0
1 0 70 1 1 0
1 0 65 1 1 0
0 2 17 2 1 0
1 1 52 2 1 0
1 0 66 1 0 0
1 1 60 2 0 0
1 1 42 1 1 0
1 1 72 2 1 0
0 0 43 2 0 0
0 0 67 1 0 1
0 0 36 1 0 0
0 2 28 2 1 0
1 1 60 1 1 0
. 0 34 1 1 0
0 0 31 1 1 0
. 0 40 2 0 0
1 0 71 1 1 0
1 1 74 1 1 0
0 0 22 1 0 0
. 2 37 1 0 0
1 2 79 2 1 1
. 2 26 2 0 1
0 1 31 2 1 0
0 0 26 2 1 0
1 2 60 2 0 1
1 0 47 2 0 0
1 2 60 2 0 1
0 2 43 2 0 1
0 2 23 1 0 0
. 0 21 2 0 0
1 0 20 2 0 0
0 1 64 2 1 0
0 2 69 2 1 0
1 2 19 2 1 0
1 1 63 1 1 0
1 0 52 2 1 0
0 2 49 2 0 0
1 0 60 2 0 0
1 0 51 1 0 1
0 0 63 1 0 0
1 2 56 1 1 0
. .  . . 0 0
end
[/CODE]
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried to replicate @dimitriy's results in Python and got slightly different results:

```
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:              mrsbinary   No. Observations:                  120
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                      114
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            5
Date:                Sat, 04 Nov 2023   Pseudo R-squ.:                 0.06093
Time:                        18:39:14   Log-Likelihood:                -77.859
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -82.911
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                   0.07234
=====================================================================================
                        coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const                -1.6980      1.206     -1.408      0.159      -4.062       0.666
endovascular          0.4169      0.685      0.609      0.543      -0.926       1.760
surgical              0.9785      0.513      1.908      0.056      -0.026       1.983
AGEatpresentation     0.0237      0.011      2.107      0.035       0.002       0.046
SEX                  -0.0670      0.398     -0.168      0.866      -0.848       0.714
presentHemorrhage     0.3632      0.404      0.898      0.369      -0.429       1.155
=====================================================================================
```

As you see, the therapy, surgical, endovascular, or both, doesn't matter. I suppose the difference comes from the encoding of the `groups`: As `statsmodels`, to my knowledge, doesn't support indicator variables natively, I had to encode them as two binary variables: `endovascular` and `surgical`, and I think this more closely represents the physical reality. I don't use Stata, so I can only guess how it deals with indicator variables internally. I assume it performs a one-hot encoding, meaning that `groups = 2` is encoded as unrelated to `groups = 1` and `groups = 0`. This doesn't seem to reflect the true state of the affairs.

Some minor points, not related to statistics:

- the scale is called '[modified Rankin Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Rankin_Scale)', after John Rankin, and usually abbreviated as 'mRS'.
- Dichotomising mRS is common, but I haven't seen dichotomisation at 0-1 / 2-6 levels. To my knowledge, people use 0-2 / 3-6, or even trichotomise (0-2, 3-5, 6), in which case ordinal regression needs to be used.

Below is my Python code for reproducibility:

```py
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

tb = pd.read_csv('cv-mRS-630427.csv', na_values='.')
tb = tb.dropna()
tb[['endovascular', 'surgical']] = 0
tb.loc[(tb.groups == 0) | (tb.groups==2), 'endovascular'] = 1
tb.loc[(tb.groups == 1) | (tb.groups==2), 'surgical'] = 1
y = tb.mrsbinary
X = tb[['endovascular', 'surgical', 'AGEatpresentation', 'SEX', 'presentHemorrhage']]
X0 = sm.add_constant(X)
logreg = sm.Logit(y, X0).fit()
logreg.summary()
```

Comment: Your model imposes the assumption that there is no interaction between getting surgery and the endovascular procedure, so the joint effect is just the sum of the individual effects. I don't know if that is a reasonable assumption here, but it alters the results.

Answer (score 5):

You can detect a positive additive effect of both surgical and endovascular, though not surgical on its own. Jointly, both effects are marginally significant. These effects are relative to just getting the endovascular procedure.

```
. logit mrsbinary i.groups AGEatpresentation i.SEX i.presentHemorrhage

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -82.910797  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -77.871283  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -77.858847  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -77.858846  

Logistic regression                                     Number of obs =    120
                                                        LR chi2(5)    =  10.10
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0723
Log likelihood = -77.858846                             Pseudo R2     = 0.0609

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          mrsbinary | Coefficient  Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             groups |
                 1  |   .5616316   .5603644     1.00   0.316    -.5366625    1.659926
                 2  |   .9785153   .5127406     1.91   0.056    -.0264378    1.983468
                    |
  AGEatpresentation |   .0237387   .0112689     2.11   0.035      .001652    .0458253
              2.SEX |  -.0670023   .3982524    -0.17   0.866    -.8475626     .713558
1.presentHemorrhage |   .3631835   .4042295     0.90   0.369    -.4290919    1.155459
              _cons |  -1.348167   .6643172    -2.03   0.042    -2.650204   -.0461288
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, dydx(*) post

Average marginal effects                                   Number of obs = 120
Model VCE: OIM

Expression: Pr(mrsbinary), predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1. groups 2. groups AGEatpresentation 2.SEX 1.presentHemorrhage

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    |            Delta-method
                    |      dy/dx std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             groups |
                 1  |   .1319928   .1299083     1.02   0.310    -.1226227    .3866083
                 2  |   .2227698   .1078579     2.07   0.039     .0113722    .4341675
                    |
  AGEatpresentation |   .0054281   .0023928     2.27   0.023     .0007383     .010118
              2.SEX |  -.0153258   .0910905    -0.17   0.866    -.1938599    .1632082
1.presentHemorrhage |   .0836836   .0929404     0.90   0.368    -.0984763    .2658435
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.

. test 1. groups

 ( 1)  1. groups = 0

           chi2(  1) =    1.03
         Prob > chi2 =    0.3096

. test 2. groups

 ( 1)  2. groups = 0

           chi2(  1) =    4.27
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0389

. test 1.groups = 2.groups = 0

 ( 1)  1. groups - 2. groups = 0
 ( 2)  1. groups = 0

           chi2(  2) =    4.58
         Prob > chi2 =    0.1012
```

Some comments. I am not sure what the aforementioned you refer to is. Second, I am not a fan of dichotomizing outcomes (unless this is standard practice in your field and not arbitrary). Finally, stroke is associated with a higher score, not with a lower.